# Different CSS files for different browsers

Tags: 6, theming

Ideally, if all of the CSS files used should be defined in the theme's .info file, how would I go about using different CSS files for different browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Conditional Stylesheets](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_styles) module allows themes to easily add conditional stylesheets to a theme's .info file.

This module is already used by the Zen, Layout Studio, and Tendu themes.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your info file

```
  ; Set the conditional stylesheets that are processed by IE.
  conditional-stylesheets[if IE][all][]       = css/ie.css
  conditional-stylesheets[if lte IE 6][all][] = css/ie6.css
```

This is taken directly from the Zen theme for Drupal 6.

Comment: OK thanks, but do I need to download a module in order for this code to work?

Comment: Yes I think you have to download the module to use the above code -- many thanks to both of the people who replied!

Comment: Nope.  Just put this code in your theme folder.  I suggest you download the Zen theme and make a sub-theme because there is a TON of instructions in the readme.txt files that will explain this for you.

Comment: The Zen theme is using the Conditional Stylesheets module, as reported in keithm's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [CSS Browser Selector](http://drupal.org/project/css_browser_selector) module which allows you to write cross-browser CSS using selectors like `.ie7`, `.ie`, `.ff`, `.safari`, etc.